# .htaccess Redirect is working incorrectly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following code in htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302,L]
```

I write the Url -> `http://www.example.com` it redirects to `http://example.com` - It works correct.
I write the Url -> `www.example.com` it redirects to `http://www./www.example.com` - It doesn't work well.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong especially in this part

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: It's *not* working *incorrectly*? So it is working correctly?

Comment: My bad. It was never working correctly. I amended the title of the question.

Comment: Your 2nd rule is redundant and not even required. Just keep first 2 lines and get rid of last 2 then clear browser cache.

Comment: @anubhava - Yeah but I want to redirect from `www.` to `http://`. How can I go about it please?

Comment: `www` to `non-www` is already happening in your first rule.

Comment: @anubhava - When I try it in my own code and http://htaccess.mwl.be/ It is telling me that 'This condition is not met.'

Comment: Show your complete .htaccess in question and also tell full URL you're using for testing.

Comment: I am using toolbox.seositecheckup.com and its telling me  `In order to pass this test you must consider using a 301 re-write rule in your .htaccess file so that both addresses (http://example.com and http://www.example.com) resolve to the same URL. `